# How to increase dimension-vector size of BERT sentence-transformers embedding

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, bert-language-model

I am using sentence-transformers for semantic search but sometimes it does not understand the contextual meaning and returns wrong result
eg. [BERT problem with context/semantic search in italian language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68627093/bert-problem-with-context-semantic-search-in-italian-language)

by default the vector side of embedding of the sentence is 78 columns, so how do I increase that dimension so that it can understand the contextual meaning in deep.

**code:**

```
# Load the BERT Model
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')

# Setup a Corpus
# A corpus is a list with documents split by sentences.

sentences = ['Absence of sanity', 
             'Lack of saneness',
             'A man is eating food.',
             'A man is eating a piece of bread.',
             'The girl is carrying a baby.',
             'A man is riding a horse.',
             'A woman is playing violin.',
             'Two men pushed carts through the woods.',
             'A man is riding a white horse on an enclosed ground.',
             'A monkey is playing drums.',
             'A cheetah is running behind its prey.']

# Each sentence is encoded as a 1-D vector with 78 columns 
sentence_embeddings = model.encode(sentences) ### how to increase vector dimention 

print('Sample BERT embedding vector - length', len(sentence_embeddings[0]))

print('Sample BERT embedding vector - note includes negative values', sentence_embeddings[0])
```

Comment: By default BERT (what is called BERT-base) word embeddings have 768 dimensions, not 78. The sentence embedding is a weighted sum of the vectors of words in the sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to INCREASE the dimension of the embedding in a meaningful way is retraining the model. :(

However, maybe this is not what you need...maybe you should consider fine-tuning a model:

I suggest you take a look at [sentence-transformers](https://www.sbert.net) from UKPLabs.
They have pretrained models for sentence embedding for over 100 languages. The best part is that you can [fine tune](https://www.sbert.net/docs/training/overview.html) those models.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

Increasing the dimension of a trained model is not possible (without many difficulties and re-training the model). The model you are using was pre-trained with dimension 768, i.e., all weight matrices of the model have a corresponding number of trained parameters. Increasing the dimensionality would mean adding parameters which however need to be learned.

Also, the dimension of the model does not reflect the amount of semantic or context information in the sentence representation. The choice of the model dimension reflects more a trade-off between model capacity, the amount of training data, and reasonable inference speed.

If the model that you are using does not provide representation that is semantically rich enough, you might want to search for better models, such as RoBERTa or T5.