# Embedding-dimension in HuggingFaceEmbeddings

Tags: python, langchain

How do I change the dimension of vector embeddings in HuggingFaceEmbeddings?

I'm trying to vectorize a list of strings using following python code snippet:

```
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()

text = ["This is a test document.",
        "This is a second document which is text."] # an example to test embeddings
```

The default dimension of each vector in 768. I need to change it to 1536. How could I possibly do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase the dimension of vector embeddings, you need to fine-tune the model.

For more information, see:

- [Can we specify the dimension of the embeddings?](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/issues/397)
- [How to increase dimension-vector size of BERT sentence-transformers embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686272/how-to-increase-dimension-vector-size-of-bert-sentence-transformers-embedding)